# can't get input type text via js

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, css-frameworks

i bought course in Udemy to make login system and just wanted to add more input in html to get username ..... but it didn't work
it took me like 15 hours and still can't understand why it don't work

```
<div class="uk-section uk-container">
    <div class="uk-grid uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-child-width-1-1" uk-grid>
        <form class="uk-form-stacked js-register">

            <h2>Register</h2>


            <div class="uk-margin">
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Username</label>
                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                    <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="text" required='required' placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>






            <div class="uk-margin">
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Email</label>
                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                    <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="email" required='required' placeholder="email@email.com">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-margin">
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Passphrase</label>
                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                    <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="password" required='required' placeholder="Your passphrase">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="uk-margin uk-alert uk-alert-danger js-error" style='display: none;'></div>

            <div class="uk-margin">
                <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.js-register", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var _form = $(this);
var _error = $(".js-error", _form);

var dataObj = {
    username: $("input[type='text']", _form).val(),
    email: $("input[type='email']", _form).val(),
    password: $("input[type='password']", _form).val()
};

if(dataObj.email.length < 6) {
    _error
        .text("Please enter a valid email address")
        .show();
    return false;
} else if (dataObj.password.length < 11) {
    _error
        .text("Please enter a passphrase that is at least 11 characters long.")
        .show();
    return false;
}

// Assuming the code gets this far, we can start the ajax process
_error.hide();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/register.php',
    data: dataObj,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
})
.done(function ajaxDone(data) {
    // Whatever data is 
    if(data.redirect !== undefined) {
        window.location = data.redirect;
    } else if(data.error !== undefined) {
        _error
            .text(data.error)
            .show();
    }
})
.fail(function ajaxFailed(e) {
    // This failed 
})
.always(function ajaxAlwaysDoThis(data) {
    // Always do
    console.log('Always');
})

return false;
})
```

php code :

```
define('__CONFIG__', true);

// Require the config
require_once "../inc/config.php"; 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' or 1==1) {
    // Always return JSON format
    // header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $return = [];

    $email = Filter::String( $_POST['email'] );

    // Make sure the user does not exist. 
    $findUser = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = LOWER(:email) LIMIT 1");
    $findUser->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $findUser->execute();

    if($findUser->rowCount() == 1) {
        // User exists 
        // We can also check to see if they are able to log in. 
        $return['error'] = "You already have an account";
        $return['is_logged_in'] = false;
    } else {
        // User does not exist, add them now. 

        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $username = $_POST['text'] ;
        $addUser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,email, password) VALUES(:username,LOWER(:email), :password)");
        $addUser->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $addUser->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $addUser->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $addUser->execute();

        $user_id = $con->lastInsertId();

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = (int) $user_id;

        $return['redirect'] = '/dashboard.php?message=welcome';
        $return['is_logged_in'] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); exit;
} else {
    // Die. Kill the script. Redirect the user. Do something regardless.
    exit('Invalid URL');
}
```

what happen that email and password send to database (which i get from source code of the course)
and username which i added just don't do anything .. prevent page from redirect
i really think i made an idiot mistake but i think 15 hours for trying is enough too .. forgive me for that .. and  for my bad English 
Thanks

Comment: You're sending username with 'username' key, not 'text' Just simply change  $username = $_POST['text']; to  $username = $_POST['username']; It will work if there's no other problems (or you can change var dataObj = {username: to text: in jquery)

Comment: @TrueTiem still same problem

Comment: can you add error log please?

Comment: @TrueTiem  added .error() to ajax in jquery nothing happed .. added try and catch in php after else statement .. no thing send to database nor echo error ... no errors in  console also .. i think i couldn't make error log maybe ...sorry for that iam beginner

Comment: Umm, Can you try echo $username and if ($addUser->execute()){echo "working";}else {$addUser->errorInfo();} I think its a php related error. And possibly a database or pdo error.

Comment: @TrueTiem didn't echo any ... it donot send email and password now too !  >>> btw i can't echo dataObj.username in jquery also !! 
maybe i had another idiot mistake than that >>

Answer (score 0):

edit this in html

```
<div class="uk-form-controls">
    <input class="uk-input" name="username" type="text" required='required' placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

and edit dataobj in ajax

```
var dataObj = {
    username: $("input[name='username']", _form).val(),
    email: $("input[type='email']", _form).val(),
    password: $("input[type='password']", _form).val()
};
```

and remove all the id's from html because you have define the same id for every html tag(username, email, paddword), javascript will throw an error if more than one html tag have the same id

Comment: There's only one input with type text. Problem is not there.

Comment: yes i know, jsut remove all the id's or define different id of textbox otherwise javascript will not work properly, you can see the error in console

Comment: try this after dataobj "console.log(dataobj.username)" and see whether you are getting the username in console or not

Comment: are you asking or telling me that jquery successfully console the username in console ? pls reply with what data you are getting in the console

Comment: i tried to console.log username .. or putting it in if() and others .. literaly no thing ! every thing same ..

Comment: console.log(username) will not show anything, console it like this console.log(dataobj.username)

Comment: @khanFarman https://codepen.io/truetiem/pen/OBaqVP as you can see, everything is fine in jquery or html part

Comment: yeah sure i did that ..no thing happened .. btw even if i console.log(dataObj.email) ... no thing happened too

Comment: send to you all files  of project soo you could see better ?

Comment: thanks for providing all the codes, i have looked into your code and ajax is working fine and is sending all the data, did you edit this line in php $username = $_POST['text'] ; to $username = $_POST['username'] ; ??

Comment: yea i did .... that's why i wanna send the whole project  !! i tried to just make it simpler and take each block of code and try it alone .. it worked .. !!! i even started to think about having apache problems so i reinstalled it 2 times !!

Comment: i literaly tried more than 15 hours !! soo i think it's advanced error or super idiot error ...

Comment: @Blank probably a database error, you should log PDO errors

Comment: @TrueTiem i donot think soo ...
by just change username value database get it ...